# SQL Aggregate In Subquery Without Duplicating Where

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate, code-duplication

So the below query works just fine, but not finding a way to not duplicate that where clause in the subquery and the outer one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE --Cannot change this as it is hardcoded in ArcGIS layer definition, only can access WHERE

objectid IN (
    SELECT objectid
    FROM table a
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT id, MIN(seq) as seq, --zone
        FROM table b 
        WHERE zone IN ( 'ZONE2', 'ZONE3', 'ZONE4') GROUP BY id) c
    ON a.id = c.id      
    AND a.seq = c.seq
    --AND a.zone = c.zone
    WHERE zone IN ( 'ZONE2', 'ZONE3', 'ZONE4') 
)
```

I essentially want to do something like the commented out pieces which would allow dropping the outer duplicated where clause... but that of course doesn't work because there is no group by.

- Cannot use MIN or MAX on zone as those are not guaranteed to be in alphabetical order based off their corresponding seq number
- Cannot GROUP BY zone as that would change the MIN(seq) returned
- Cannot do the WHERE in just the outer query as the subquery would not get the right MIN(seq)
- Cannot do the WHERE just in the inner query as there might be duplicate seq numbers in other zones

We have about 15 variations of the zones in the WHERE clause and they will slowly change over time. So just trying to minimize the duplication which might help the long term reliability of switching them out.

Thanks a lot for any ideas and help!

Comment: You can probably do this without a join and without correlated subqueries, using analytic function(s) instead. It would help to show table structure, intended result, and sample data (simple enough yet with enough "trouble" rows to illustrate the various problems that may arise).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you looked using a common table expression (CTE)

A CTE is kind of like a reusable subquery.

Comment: At first I didn't think this would work because as mentioned I don't control the SELECT and the WITH needed to be first. But the WITH works inside the IN before the first subquery. This way both the subqueries can use the filtered dataset. Will test a little more and then vote this up and post the solution

Comment: Oh, I see.  I didn't actually answer the question, just pointed to a technique.

Comment: I actually was suggesting trying to shape that outer query with a CTE and a window function which probably could not be made work (easily) given the initial constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE --Cannot change this as it is hardcoded in ArcGIS layer definition, only can access
objectid IN (
  SELECT objectid
  FROM   (
    SELECT objectid,
           seq,
           MIN( seq ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id /*, zone */ ) AS min_seq
    FROM   table
    WHERE  zone IN ( 'ZONE2', 'ZONE3', 'ZONE4')
  )
  WHERE seq = min_seq
)
```

Comment: This works too, thanks. Hmm, now which option is better... using a PARTITION or the WITH. A little less code with the PARTITION. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE --Cannot change this as it is hardcoded in ArcGIS layer definition, only can access
WHERE objectid IN (SELECT a.objectid
                   FROM table a
                   WHERE a.seq = (SELECT min(seq) 
                                  FROM table b 
                                  WHERE b.zone = a.zone AND a.id = c.id
                                 ) AND
                        a.zone IN ( 'ZONE2', 'ZONE3', 'ZONE4') 
                  );
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks a lot for the speedy reply. This is actually one of the first ways I actually tried but am getting back a lot more records... not just the MIN(seq) per id. I think its because the subquery is narrowed down to a single matching zone then getting the MIN, it needs the MIN of the same group of zones. Assuming in your example that should not be c.id but b.id, as there is no more c.

Comment: @Cood . . . I think you should try to get something like this to work.  CTEs are useful, but it seems to be papering something over in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based off Darrel's suggestion to use CTE I found that a WITH clause could be used inside the outer query. I always thought they could only be used at the beginning. Here is code that works:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE --Cannot change this as it is hardcoded in ArcGIS layer definition, only can access WHERE

objectid IN (
    with filtered_zones as (
        select objectid , id, zone, seq
        from table 
        where zone in ( 'ZONE2', 'ZONE3', 'ZONE4'))
    SELECT objectid
    FROM filtered_zones a
    JOIN (
        SELECT id, MIN(seq) as seq
        FROM filtered_zones b 
        GROUP BY id) c
    ON a.id = c.id      
    AND a.seq = c.seq)
```